# Laziness of Haskell and list comprehension. Completion condition

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

`foo s1 s2 = null ([x | x <- s2, x == s1])`

Please explain when this function will end?

Will Haskell first iterate through the entire list and then check for `null`, or when one element appears, will he check for `null` and complete the iteration? If the first option, then how can it be made more lazy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will Haskell first iterate through the entire list and then check for `null`.

**No**. `null` checks if it is an empty list, and returns `True` for an empty list `[]`, and `False` for the `(:)` data constructor. The "old" [`null` is implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#null):

> ```
> null                    :: [a] -> Bool
> null []                 =  True
> null (_:_)              =  False
> ```

It will thus evaluate the list comprehension to *head normal form* (HNF), and once it knows the outer data constructor it can return `True` or `False`: it will not check what the first element is, so if that is an expensive expression, it will not waste time on that one either.

The "new" [`null` is implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#null):

> ```
> null :: t a -> Bool
> null = foldr (\_ _ -> False) True
> ```

where [`foldr` for a list is implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr):

> ```
> foldr k z = go
>           where
>             go []     = z
>             go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
> ```

which will thus also simply check if the outer data constructor is an empty list `[]` or a "cons" `(:)` since in this case `k` returns `True` and is not interested in the parameters.

List comprehensions are lazy as well: these will only evaluate the outer data constructor if necessary, and construct the head and tail if necessary. Your list comprehension is desugared to:

```
concatMap (\x -> if x == s1 then [x] else []) s2
```

If it thus has to evaluate the outer data constructor of the list, it will iterate over `s2`, if `x == s1` then it will produce as outer data constructor the "cons" and then `null` can thus use that to determine if the list is empty.

This thus means that from the moment it finds an element `x` from `s2` where `x == s1`, it will return `False`.